# Is it possible to find a multivariate polynomial solution of a PDE?

Tags: polynomials, partial-differential-equations

Let us consider the folowing PDE:

$$-βδy^{β-1}z^{δ-1}\frac{∂f}{∂x}+αδx^{α-1}\frac{∂f}{∂y}-αβx^{α-1}y^{β-1}\frac{∂f}{∂z}=c \tag{*}$$

where $x,y,z$, are the variables, $α,β,δ$ are positive integers, and $c$ is  a constant not depending on $x,y,z$.

My **question** is: Is it possible to find a multivariate polynomial function in $x,y,z$ solution of $(*)$?

Comment: Is not $z^{δ-1}$ missing in the second term ?

Comment: @JJacquelin: No, it is the right equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-βδy^{β-1}z^{δ-1}\frac{∂f}{∂x}+αδx^{α-1}\frac{∂f}{∂y}-αβx^{α-1}y^{β-1}\frac{∂f}{∂z}=c$$
The general solution can be expressed on the form (calculus below) :
$$f(x,y,z)=-\frac{c}{\alpha\beta}\Phi\big((x^\alpha-z^\delta)\:,\:(y^\beta+\delta z) \big)\int_{z_0}^z (x^\alpha-z^\delta+\xi)^{(1/\alpha)-1}(y^\beta+\delta z+\delta\xi^{1/\delta})^{(1/\beta)-1}d\xi$$ 
In case of $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ integers :

If $\Phi$ is a an arbitrary polynomial function of two variables, then $\Phi\big(x^\alpha-z^\delta)\:,\:(y^\beta+\delta z)\big)$ is a polynomial wrt $x,y,z$ .

So, the question is "Can the integral be a polynomial ? "

The answer is NO in general because the fractional exponents $\frac{1}{\alpha},\,\frac{1}{\beta},\,\frac{1}{\delta}$ are not integers.

But in some particular cases, it can be a polynomial. For example in case of $\alpha=\beta=\delta=1$ the general solution is reduced to particular solutions of the form :
$$f(x,y,z)=-c\:z\:\Phi\big((x-z)\:,\:(y+z) \big)$$
with arbitrary polynomial function $\Phi$. In these particular cases, the solutions of the PDE are polynomials.

CALCULUS :

[image]